# loop over all text and do certain actions to bullets

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The following for-looop returns only NavigableString-objects for text, and no TAG-Objects.

```
for paragraph in report.find('body').find_all(text=True):
```

I would like to use conditional statements based on the tag inside my for loop to do different Things With bullet Points ('li'). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop through TAG `find_all(True)`

```
for paragraph in report.find('body').find_all(True):
    hasChild = paragraph.findChildren()
    if(len(hasChild) == 0):
        if paragraph.name == 'li':
            print('bullet: ' + paragraph.text)
        else:
            print(paragraph.text)
```

Comment: This almost works. The only problem is that the first Tag in the loop now contains the entire text of the body.